# Taba de Div de 2x2

Tags: html, css

[image: Referencia]

Hola, necesito ayuda con una tabla de div tengo creada usando  pero el div "D" queda muy abajo y no se ajusta al margen del div "C", se ubica debajo del div "E"
Necesito que quede como el la imagen la tabla de div, es necesariamente el uso de los div no con tablas

```css
.tab {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.contenedor-columna1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 800px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.contenedor-columna2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.contenedor-columna3 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 800px;
  height: 520px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.contenedor-columna4 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">

  <div class="contenedor-columna1">Columna 1</div>
  <div class="contenedor-columna2">Columna 2</div>
  <div class="contenedor-columna3">Columna 3</div>
  <div class="contenedor-columna4">Columna 4</div>

</div>
```

Comment: [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) te puede servir de manera excelente

Comment: Una buena forma de hacer esto no la única) es usando columnas Bootstrap. La gracias que tiene esta forma es que se pueden aplicar a diferentes formatos de dispositivos. Pudes ver más información aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que en la regla de **.contenedor-columna2** especificamente en el selector **float** tenía la declaración **left**, basta con cambiarlo a **right**, es decir **float: right**

Y para finalizar en el **.contenedor-columna3** agregarle **margin-top: 20px;** para que quede como en la imagen.

En conclusión el código quedaría:

```css
.tab{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;   
    border : 2px solid black; 
}
.contenedor-columna1{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    height: 60px;  
    border: 1px solid black;
}
 .contenedor-columna2{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: 20px; 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: right;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;  
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.contenedor-columna3{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    height: 520px;  
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.contenedor-columna4{
    margin-left: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    float: right;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;  
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
    <div class="contenedor-columna1">Columna 1</div>
    <div class="contenedor-columna2">Columna 2</div>
    <div class="contenedor-columna3">Columna 3</div>
    <div class="contenedor-columna4">Columna 4</div>
</div>
```